# Apache mod_remoteip and access logs

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, x-forwarded-for

Since Apache **2.4** I've started using **mod_remoteip** instead of **mod_extract_forwarded** for rewriting client address from **x-forwarded-for** provided by frontend servers (varnish, squid, apache etc).

So far everything works fine with the modules, i.e. php, cgi, wsgi etc... - client addresses are shown as they should be, but I couldn't write client address in access logs (%a, %h, %{c}a). No luck - I'm always getting 127.0.0.1 (localhost forward ex.).

How to log client's ip address when using mod_remoteip?

Update: **IT WORKS O_O** - see answer below

Comment: you might want to add the specific config you use/tested.

Additionally, while not in details, this might help:
http://knowledgevoid.com/blog/2012/01/13/logging-the-correct-ip-address-using-apache-2-2-x-and-amazons-elastic-load-balancer/
I assume you did read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html#page-header aswell?

stackexchange has a few questions you might want to read:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455731/getting-apache-2-4-access-logs-to-show-client-ip-instead-of-127-0-0-1-with-varni

Comment: re-built configuration, now it works O_O

Answer (score 21, accepted):

varnish configuration:

```
if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
}
```

apache 2.4 configuration sections:

mod_remoteip:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.1/8
```

logging (%a does the job):

```
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

+

if there is a nginx in front (ex. SSL termination):

```
server {
    listen       123.123.123.123:443;
    server_name  server.com;
    root         html;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/httpd/site/chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/httpd/site/private.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:6081;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you accept this answer, you should award the bounty, even if it's your own answer.

Comment: Would you please update this, or give us the variation for http.cf-connecting-ip from CloudFlare? Have not had any luck making it to work, sorry.

Comment: You should actually use $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for instead of $remote_addr for Nginx X-Forwarded-For. That does the same functionality as the Varnish example, whereas $remote_addr doesn't include previous X-Forwarded-For values

Answer (score 5):

According to [mod_remoteip's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html), the module should simply replace the client IP address, but only when `RemoteIPHeader x-forwarded-for` is set ([doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html#remoteipheader)).
Also make sure, your vhost's logging makes use of the CustomLog you have defined.

Comment: this should be accepted answer